# How to pass data from User.php to page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

If user logged in I find his IP address and would pass it to a page. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (Auth::check())
 {
   $ip = Request::ip();
   return view('example-component')->with('ip', $ip);
 }
```

In ExampleComponent

```
  <h1>Hello, {{$ip}}</h1>
```

I get below-given error

View [example-component] not found.

Maybe I can't return view if it's not inside a function?

Comment: use `if (Auth::user())`

Comment: Well, I got IP but I can't pass it to the view.

Comment: Laravel cannot find the file `resources/views/example-component.blade.php`. Make sure that the "example-component" view has the file extension `blade.php`and is in the `resources/views` directory.

Comment: @OneBigOwnage It is set up correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the file name is exactly "example-component.blade.php"? If it isn't the right case, it cannot be found. For example; `ExampleComponent.blade.php` isn't the same as `example-component.blade.php`.